# Problemas generalizados em C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Nome "nome"
#define TAM_STRING 12

void main(void)
{
    char * str;

    str = (char*) malloc(TAM_STRING);

    if(str == NULL)
    {
        printf("Não já espaço para alocar");
    }
    else { (str,Nome);
    printf("Nome=[%s] tem [%d] caracters",str, strlen(Nome));
    int i = 0;
    for( i=0;i<strlen(Nome);i++)
    {
        printf("\nCaracter[%d] = [%c]\n", i , *(str+i));
        if(((*(str+i)=='a')|| (*(str+i)=='e'))|| (*(str+i)=='i')||(*(str+i)=='o')||(*(str+i)=='u')) printf("Vogal");
    }
}
free(str);
}
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: O que o código deveria fazer? O que ele está fazendo?

Comment: `*(str+i)` é igual a `str[i]`. Na minha opinião o último formato é mais fácil de ler.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

O código tem alguns erros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // <=========== faltava este include
#define Nome "nome"
#define TAM_STRING 12

int main(void) { // <========== o retorno aqui precisa ser um int
    char * str = malloc(TAM_STRING); // <======= a declaração pode e deve ser mais simples
    if (str == NULL) printf("Não já espaço para alocar");
    else { 
        strcpy(str, Nome); // <======= acredito que queria usar esta função, não tinha o nome dela
        int tamanho = strlen(Nome);
        printf("Nome=[%s] tem [%d] caracters", str, tamanho);
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            printf("\nCaracter[%d] = [%c]\n", i , str[i]);
            if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u') printf("Vogal");
        }
        free(str);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6Dfevq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mwocnyjn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futur](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/IncludeStdlib.c)a.

Parte do problema é que o código estava mal formatado, fica difícil achar erros assim. Eu mudaria mais algumas coisas, mesmo considerando que isto é algo só para testar e que não faz nada útil e com qualidade de produção. De fato mudei algumas coisas.